# How can I invert a slice?

Tags: python, slice

My code right now

```
sentence = "Sentence!"
print(*sentence[::3], sep="--")
```

Output: `S--t--c`

How am I able to invert the slice so that same input would result in `-en-en-e!`

I've tried doing -3 and different numbers in the `::3` but none work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
sentence = 'Sentence!'

import re
tokens = re.findall(r'.(..)', sentence)
print('', '-'.join(tokens), sep='-')  # prints:  -en-en-e!
```

---

Edit:  Addressing the question in the comments:

> This works, although how can I get this to start on the 3rd letter?

You could try this:

```
tokens = re.findall(r'(..).?', sentence[2:])
print(*tokens, sep='-')
```

This will output:  `nt-nc`

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: This will drop off the last part if the length of the string isn't a multiple of three.

Comment: @kaya3:  Agreed.  But I figured that since the original poster's code gave output of 'S--t--c', which dropped off the last part (the final `--`), (s)he was more concerned about doing the inversion of `string[::3]` than about keeping the remainder around.  (If that's not true, then the original poster should be able to modify the code to handle non-multiples of 3.)

Comment: How would I make it add multiples of 3? `tokens = re.findall(r'.(..)', '(..)', sentence)` tried stuff like this and it doesn't work

Comment: @3891, I'm not sure what you mean by "make it add multiples of 3".  Are you trying to output a sum total?

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to achieve isn't possible using a slice, because the indices you want to keep (1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8) are not an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Since the goal is to replace the first character of every three with a `-` symbol, the simplest solution I can think of is using a regex:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(".(.{0,2})", r"-\1", "Sentence!")
'-en-en-e!'
>>> re.sub(".(.{0,2})", r"-\1", "Hello, world!")
'-el-o,-wo-ld-'
```

The `{0,2}` means the pattern will match even if the last group doesn't have three letters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to truly invert the range, then take the indices *not* in that range:

```
''.join(sentence[i] if i not in range(0, len(sentence), 3) else '-'
        for i in range(len(sentence)))
```

Output

```
'-en-en-e!'
```

Personally, I prefer the regex solutions.

Comment: I like this solution because it's as close as you can get to a direct inversion of the slicing logic, and it is more obvious how to adapt it to invert different slices.

Comment: Thanks.  This adapts to a variety of things to invert, but it's notably wordy as a result.

Comment: It can be made a bit briefer using `enumerate`.

Comment: Yes; I usually try to keep the "new technology" (beyond the original post) to a minimum.  I already had a conditional comprehension and `join`.

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt:

```
sentence = ("Sentence!")
print(''.join(ch if i % 3 else '-' for i, ch in enumerate(sentence)))
```

Prints:

```
-en-en-e!
```

---

If `sentence='Hello, world!'`:

```
-el-o,-wo-ld-
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice assignment:

```
def invert(string, step, sep):
    sentence = list(string)
    sentence[::step] = len(sentence[::step]) * [sep]
    return ''.join(sentence)

print(invert('Sentence!', 3, '*'))
# *en*en*e!

print(invert('Hallo World!', 4, '$'))
# $all$ Wo$ld!
```